# django rest framework DefaultRouter error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I wrote a program to learn django rest framework, but the program I wrote is not executed correctly. I have been looking for it for a long time. I can't find the error. I need someone to help me check the problem from another perspective. Thank you.

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Subsystem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=36)


class Menu(models.Model):
    subsystem = models.ForeignKey(Subsystem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=36)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from subsystem.models import Subsystem, Menu


class SubsystemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Subsystem
        fields = ('name', )


class MenuSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = ('name', 'subsystem')
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from subsystem.models import Subsystem, Menu
from subsystem.api.serializers import SubsystemSerializer, MenuSerializer


class SubsystemViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Subsystem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SubsystemSerializer(queryset)


class MenuViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Menu.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MenuSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from subsystem.api.views import SubsystemViewSet
router = DefaultRouter()

router.registry(r'subsystems', SubsystemViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

I started trying to run python manage.py runserver  but it can't run

error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x06125FA8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 397, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 536, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\sc\oa\oaapi\oaapi\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    router.registry(r'subsystems', SubsystemViewSet)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I modified views.py

```
class SubsystemViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Subsystem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SubsystemSerializer
```

But the error still exists
detail:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x065F5FA8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 397, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 536, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "D:\env\python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\sc\oa\oaapi\oaapi\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    router.registry(r'subsystems', SubsystemViewSet)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewSet's `serializer_class`  should be class itself, not it's instance. You should use `serializer_class = SubsystemSerializer` instead of `serializer_class = SubsystemSerializer(queryset)`.Rewrite `SubsystemViewSet` to this:

```
class SubsystemViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Subsystem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SubsystemSerializer
```

Also it should be `register` instead of `registry`:

```
router.register(r'subsystems', SubsystemViewSet)
```

You can find example of routers usage [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage).